# Perl script can't open file owned by root when called from process (Nagios)

Tags: linux, perl, nagios

I have a VPS with Nagios installed, and I want to use Nagios to monitor the VPS resources in the */proc/user_beancounters* file. The file has the following permissions:

```
-r-------- 1 root root 0 Oct 26 15:53 /proc/user_beancounters
```

So I downloaded the script from the Nagios Exchange:

https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/*-Virtual-Environments/OpenVZ/check-beancounters/details

In the instructions it suggests to:

```
don’t forget to set the s-bit (chmod +s check_UBC.pl)
```

So, I copied the script over, and set the s-bit, then run it from the terminal as root. It works as expected. I then delete the temp file it created, su into the nagios user, and run the script. It works as expected. I delete the temp file it created, and start up Nagios. It can't read the */proc/user_beancounters* file! The exact error I get, helpfully, is "could not read /proc/user_beancounters". This is, I believe, thrown by the line in the Perl script:

```
if (! open IN, "<", $UBC )
{
    print "could not read $UBC\n";
    exit $ERRORS{'CRITICAL'};
}
```

My OS is *CentOS release 6.2 (Final)*.

My first thought is that it is some kind of SELinux voodoo, but there is no indication that SELinux is running on this server. Just in case, I tried the following:

```
echo 0 > /selinux/enforce
```

But this made no difference.

For reference, this is my nagios service running:

```
nagios   12939  0.0  0.0 203652  3404 ?        Ssl  15:39   0:00 /usr/sbin/nagios -d /etc/nagios/nagios.cfg
```

And this is where I've put the Perl script:

```
-rwsr-sr-x 1 nagios nagios   2934 Oct 26 15:37 check_UBC.pl
```

Any suggestions as to what else I can try?

PS apologies if this should go in a different SE site - never sure with questions that involve scripts, permissions etc...

**UPDATE 1**

I created a shell script to see if I could 'emulate' the nagios service. It is extremely simple:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_UBC.pl
```

And now I have the following permissions:

```
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root     2934 Oct 26 15:37 check_UBC.pl
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root       51 Oct 26 19:29 check_UBC.sh
```

As root:

```
[root@/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins]$ ./check_UBC.pl 
  everything is fine..
[root@/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins]$ ./check_UBC.sh 
  everything is fine..
```

As nagios:

```
-bash-4.1$ ./check_UBC.pl
  everything is fine..
-bash-4.1$ ./check_UBC.sh
  everything is fine..
```

So still no clue...

**UPDATE 2**

My nagios command definition:

```
define command{
    command_name    check_beancounters
    command_line    $USER1$/check_UBC.pl
    }
```

And the service definition:

```
define service{
    use                             local-service
    host_name                       localhost
    service_description             VPS Beancounters
    check_command                   check_beancounters
    }
```

**UPDATE 3**

I managed to get it to work, but am not over the moon about giving the nagios user full sudo access with no password. In /etc/sudoers I put this on the last line:

```
nagios ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

And then changed my command definition to:

```
define command{
    command_name    check_beancounters
    command_line    sudo $USER1$/check_UBC.pl
    }
```

Apparently recent versions of linux will not respect the +s permission when running an interpreted script, only a binary. So I guess I will have to compile a binary wrapper for the script?

**UPDATE 4**

As per Joe Young's suggestion, I changed my visudo entry to:

```
nagios ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_UBC.pl
```

Which hopefully is relatively harmless!

Comment: I am finding in the later versions of RedHat-based Linux distributions I've been working on that setting the UID -- 's' -- bit is no longer letting the script or program act like it's root. I would contact the Nagios bulletin boards, unless this is a commercial product, and you're paying for support. For example, I've wanted a shell script to go create a file in /var/lib, because our payments web site looks there to see if a payment "lock out" file exists. It prevents payments from coming in when we do not want them too. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts

Comment: What is weird is that when I "su - nagios" and then run the script myself, it runs fine. When the nagios service runs the script, it fails. I read somewhere about disabling "requiretty" - could it be to do with this?

Comment: Then it seems SUID nagios might work.

Comment: If you don't want to allow nagios access to `ALL`, you can replace the final `ALL` with the path to your script.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the owner of `check_UBC.pl` to `root` so that when nagios executes `check_UBC.pl` the script runs as setuid of it's owner `root` and not the `nagios` user.

```
chown root:root check_UBC.pl
```

**EDIT:**

Can you post your command definition that's calling `check_UBC.pl`?

The last thing I can think of to try is to install the perl-suid module:  https://chrisjean.com/fix-setuid-cannot-exec-sperl/
Although, if `check_UBC.pl` runs from the command line with no problem, I'm not sure what difference it would make.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - didn't help though. Anything else I can try? Maybe I could take out the +s permission, add nagios to the sudoers list, and call the script with "sudo ./myscript" instead? Might that work?

Comment: Updated with the command and service definitions. When I first tried to run it, it failed because I didn't have the perl-suid, so I have already installed that. I didn't configure anything after I installed it though, so if the defaults won't work then that could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

What would the risk be to change the permissions on /proc/user_beancounters to 444 (read for all?) It only contains a number, correct?  Not sure if that particular file "sticks around" after a reboot, or worse, constantly gets replaced as the services are running, so this could be a problem still.

Also, consider trying to test for actual "existence" of the file, before you attempt to read from it. Since we're in /proc directory, things do change, from time to time....

Lastly, you are asking to open the file, but syntactically is it asking to open in a read only mode? You may want to try a system call to simply "cat" the file contents, in your shell script, and see if you get a response.